# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException after shutdownNow() in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have an `ExecutorService` (thread pool size = 4) that is handling a number of Callables. Each of them opens a database connection (Hikari Connection pool) and closes it again.

If I now call shutdownNow() on the `ExecutorService` I do also wait for the termination of the currently running tasks. However, eventhough `awaitTermination` does not produce a timeout - thus all running tasks should have been terminated, and all database operations should have finished - I get an `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException` stating the following:

```
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading from nio:database.mv.db failed; file length -1 read length 256 at 711665 [1.4.196/1]"; SQL statement: SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE id = ? [50000-196]
```

In addition, I do close the Hikari connection pool far later than shutting down the ExecutorService. Do you have any ideas what I could search for?

EDIT:

Here is the basic code structure - I think I have mentioned all necessary items. Note, that the exception mentioned does not get thrown every time - but most of the time:

```
class DatabaseManager {
    private HikariDataSource datasource;
    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    public static DatabaseManager getInstance() { 
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public Connection getConnection() { datasource.getConnection(); }
    private DatabaseManager() {
        // initialize with parameters for a H2 database
        this.datasource = new HikariDataSource();
    }
    public void shutdown() {
        if (this.datasource != null) {
            this.datasource.shutdown();
        }
        this.datasource = null;
    }
}

class SimpleCallable extends Callable<SomeType> {
    String information;
    public SomeCallable(String info) { this.information = info; }
    public SomeType call() {
        // omitted try-catch
        Connection connection = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getConnection();
        // doing some things with connection (reading and writing data), the Method invoked is static and synchronized
        // within this method the exception mentioned above is thrown
        SomeType someType = SomeTypeHelper.transferToDB(connection, information);
        connection.close();
        return someType;
    }
}

class SimpleTask extends Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ExecutorService service = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            SimpleCallable callable = new SimpleCallable("random text");
            FutureTask task = new FutureTask(callable);
            service.submit(task);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // nothing to do
        }
        service.shutdownNow();
        try {
            if (!service.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("timeout"); // but will never be printed
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // nothing to do
        }
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleTask task = new SimpleTask();
        new Thread(task).start();
        DatabaseManager.getInstance().shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to ask ?

Comment: See: http://h2database.com/html/features.html#closing_a_database

Comment: Can you show us little more code? Looks like the callable tasks are not happy when their runner tasks are interrupted during an sql query.